# App name in the navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a sample app as a learner. How do I fix the code below to have "One Month Rails" appear on every page of my app, in the left of my navigation bar? Thank you!

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </a>

            <% link_to "One Month Rails", root_path, class: "brand" %>

            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to 'Home',  root_path %>
                    </li>
                    <li>    
                        <%= link_to 'About',  about_path %>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                  <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                  <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
                  <% end %>
        </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you...

```
<%= Rails.application.class.parent_name %>
```

Or more specifically...

```
<%= link_to Rails.application.class.parent_name, root_path, class: "brand" %>
```

Don't forget the equals sign in front of the link_to call.

Comment: Seems I had only forgotten the equals sign.. Thank you!